# Remote debug from win10 to linux_x86_64 with gdbserver via VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, containers, gdbserver

I have win10 host and a ubuntu target(a docker container) (same x86_64). I run gdbserver on the target,on an hello world (c code) elf, and i have gdb.exe (cross-compiled with mingw64) client on my host. I am able to debug the app correctly from windows using gdb command line.
On target: gdbserver localhost:9000 /home/tmp/app2
On Host: target remote localhost:9000

I want to debug with Vscode instead of command line.
I wrote a launch.json as follow:

```
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
            "executable": "app2",
            "target": "localhost:9000",
            "remote": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}", 
            "gdbpath": "C:\\work\\gdb.exe"
        }
```

Nothing seems to happen and i can't see any output log.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right JSON file.

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
        {

```
        "type": "cppdbg", 
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "GDB",
        "program": "C:\\work\\app2",
        "miDebuggerPath":"gdb.exe" ,
        "miDebuggerServerAddress" : "localhost:9000",
        "cwd": ".", 
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        },
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        "windows": {
            "MIMode": "gdb"
        }
    }
]
```

}